# Python, DataFrame, looking the biggest 10 values in each column

Tags: python, list, pandas, numpy, dataframe

It is my first question here; sorry for any mistakes.

I have data frame that looks like the ones below:

```
           points                                                 
round     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9      
id                                                                       
3        0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  3.0  2.0     
4        0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     
5        0.0  3.0  7.0 -1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    
7        0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    
10       0.0  2.0  7.0 -2.0  1.0 -1.0  0.0  0.0  3.0  0.0  
12       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
14       0.0  0.0  0.0 -2.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  2.0  5.0  2.0
15       0.0  0.0  0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
18       0.0  4.0  4.0  0.0  9.0  2.0  0.0  3.0  1.0  0.0
```

And I need to find 3 biggest values in each columns and return then in a list of their IDs; for example:

```
round_1 = [5,10,4]

round_2 = [5,10,18]
```

and etc., and if values are the same like in round 3:

```
round_3 = [15,7,3,4,12,18] and etc
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can using `nlargest` , ps : index is your round here

```
df.apply(lambda x : x.nlargest(3)).stack().groupby(level=1).apply(list)
Out[523]: 
0    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
1    [3.0, 2.0, 4.0]
2    [7.0, 7.0, 4.0]
3    [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
4    [1.0, 1.0, 9.0]
5    [1.0, 1.0, 2.0]
6    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
7    [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
8    [3.0, 3.0, 5.0]
9    [2.0, 0.0, 2.0]
dtype: object
```

Update

```
s=df.apply(lambda x : x.nlargest(3)).notnull()
s.mul(s.index.values,axis=0).replace(0,np.nan).stack().astype(int).groupby(level=1).apply(list)
Out[564]: 
0      [3, 4, 5]
1    [5, 10, 18]
2    [5, 10, 18]
3     [3, 7, 15]
4    [3, 10, 18]
5    [3, 14, 18]
6      [3, 4, 5]
7    [3, 14, 18]
8    [3, 10, 14]
9     [3, 4, 14]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for so quick respond but I need to return theri ID, not the specific values. So for round 1 the output should be
round_1 = [5,10,4]

Comment: @galanonim check the update , also if this is what you need can you consider accept it

Comment: this is excatly what I need, but when I try to run code I have:
ValueError: cannot evaluate a numeric op with unequal lengths
no idea how to fix it

Comment: @galanonim tey `s.mul(s.index.values,axis=0).replace(0,np.nan).stack().astype(int).groupby(level=1).apply(list)`

Comment: it helped but in my result I don't have ID numbers but

round

0     [points]
1     [points]

2     [points]

3     [points]

4     [points]

5     [points]

6     [points]

7     [points]

8     [points]

9     [points]

10    [points]

Comment: that's my cod:
`s = pd.pivot_table(s, index=['id'], values=['points'], columns=['round'])`

s = s.apply(lambda x : x.nlargest(3)).notnull()

`s = s.mul(s.index.values,axis=0).replace(0,np.nan).stack().astype(int).groupby(level=1).apply(list)`